# Calling a method once reader.onload is finished executing

Tags: javascript, filereader

I am trying to fire a method once my **`reader.onload`** finishes fetching the data and so that I can use that data in my method.

I am having hard time achieving that as you see in below snippet. Wherever I execute  **`doOnLoad()`** method I am always getting undefined.

Please help

```js
onFileChange(ev) {
    let workBook = null;
    let jsonData = null;
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const file = ev.target.files[0];
    reader.onload = event => {
      const data = reader.result;
      workBook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'binary' });
      jsonData = workBook.SheetNames.reduce((initial, name) => {
        const sheet = workBook.Sheets[name];
        initial[name] = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet);
        return initial;
      }, {});
      const dataString = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
      // console.log(dataString);
      configFile = dataString;
      //  doOnLoad(configFile);
    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    doOnLoad(configFile);
}

  
doOnLoad(config) {
  console.log(config);  // Getting Undefined
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explanation

Let's consider a simple example where a file input is taken. To read the file, you would need `reader` to call `readAsText()` method. Once, the reader has loaded the file, it would fire a load event and the event would be handled by `reader.onload`.

So, in order to access the file content you need to write the code **inside the event handler**, i.e. `reader.onload`, else if you log `fileContent` just after `reader.readAsText()`, this line of code would execute **before** the reader even **finished loading** the file.

```js
// Callback from a <input type="file" onchange="onChange(event)">

const onChange = (event) => {
  var file = event.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();

  let fileContent;

  reader.onload = (e) => {
    fileContent = e.target.result;

    // the file's text will be logged here
    console.log(fileContent);
  };

  reader.readAsText(file);
  console.log(fileResult); // undefined as reader didn’t finish loading the file
}
```

#### Solution

Move `doOnLoad(configFile);` inside `reader.onload` event handler.

```js
// rest of the code

reader.onload = (event) => {
  // rest of the code
  configFile = dataString;
  doOnLoad(configFile);
};

reader.readAsBinaryString(file);

// rest of the code
```